# How to rename uploaded file to Username in php?

Tags: php

How to write code for to upload the file that file should be saved with Username instead of original name.

```
 <?php
    if ($_POST['upload'] )
     {
     $user=$_session['username'];// current username
     //$filename=basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);



     $tmp=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
      $extension = explode("/", $_FILES["file"]["type"]);
      $name=$user.".".$extension[1];

    move_uploaded_file($tmp, "upload/" . $user.".".$extension[1]);
     }  

 ?>
```

Error :

> Notice: Undefined variable: _session in C:\xampp\htdocs\aaa\upload
>   file.php on line

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please don't paste your code in the comment instead edit your post with the code.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: yes,Notice: Undefined variable: _session in C:\xampp\htdocs\aaa\upload file.php on line 4

Comment: have u tried calling session at the top `session_start()` after `<?php`

Comment: yes but no luck

Comment: I think `$_session` should be written as `$_SESSION`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```
   <?php
    if ($_POST['upload'] )
   {
       $user=$_SESSION['username'];// current username

        $filename = $user."_".$_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $newFilePath = "./upload/".$filename;

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$newFilePath)) 
         {
              return true;
         }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

  }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

start the session on very top line and session should be always in **upper case** i.e. **SESSION** .

Please consider the below code :-

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_POST['upload'] )
 {
 $user=$_SESSION['username'];// current username
 //$filename=basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

 $tmp=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  $extension = explode("/", $_FILES["file"]["type"]);
  $name=$user.".".$extension[1];

move_uploaded_file($tmp, "upload/" . $name);
```

Answer (score 0):

While the user logs in did you start the session at that time and stored it in the session variable you are using i.e. $_session['username']

Answer (score 0):

php SESSION syntax error

```
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
```

- [`$_SESSION`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) is a special [superglobal variable](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) and needs to be in uppercase.